# Null Return on API Call

Tags: java, android-studio, openweathermap

I'm working on building a weather app using the Open Weather API. The below properly calls the API but for some reason returns null.

```
JSONObject queryResults = data.optJSONObject("weather");
            System.out.println(queryResults.toString());
```

Here is the API Call

[API Call Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7HPC.png)

When I put in "coord" or "main" or "clouds" or "sys", it works perfectly I get the results. But for some reason, just with "weather" it returns null. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Show how you get the `data` object.

Comment: Weather is an array, you should use some jsonarray reader

Comment: asfmlr got it! It's a JSONArray, though it returns some weird data, it actually returns the data now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use JSONArray. Thanks to asfmlr in the comments above.